# compare 7 tab delimited files, print similarities

Tags: python, csv, comparison

I want to compare 7 different files for the same rows and show the entries that are present in multiple files. for example

```
file1:
ID123    columns with info
ID456    columns with info
ID789    columns with info

file 2:
ID123    columns with info
ID999    columns with info
ID888    columns with info

file3:
ID999    columns with info
ID123    columns with info
ID555    columns with info
```

then I want to print/show something similar like:

```
file1 and file2 and file3: ID123
file2 and file3: ID999, ID123
```

I already have something like this:

```
with open('some_file_1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('some_file_2.txt', 'r') as file2:
        same = set(file1).intersection(file2)

same.discard('\n')

with open('some_output_file.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in same:
        file_out.write(line)
```

but In this case I want to compare 7 files. Additionally, it is a tab delimited file, so I want to compare the first column of every file with each other and write down the duplicates. I think I need an

```
for i in excelList[1:]:                    
   newlist = newlist.append(i.split("\t")[0])
```

Or something like that. Even if I make 7 lists, it is quite impossible to compare them with each other with the ".intersection" code.

Is there an easier way to archieve this?

Comment: Mostly unrelated, but you may want to use the stdlib's csv module instead - parsing csv can be much more tricky than just splitting on the seprator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `dict` mapping ids to lists of filenames:

```
from collections import defaultdict

id_to_files = defaultdict(list)

for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delim="\t", ...)
        for row in reader:
            id = row[0]
            id_to_files[id].append(filename)
```

So you'd get something like:

```
print(id_to_files)

{
    "ID123": ["file1", "file2", "file3"],
    "ID999": ["file2", "file3"],
    "ID888": ["file2"],
    "ID555": ["file3"],
    "ID456": ["file1"],
    "ID789": ["file1"],
}
```

which you can then filter to remove entries with a single file listed (since those are not duplicates):

```
duplicates = {k:v for k, v in id_to_files.iteritems() if len(v) > 1}
print(duplicates)

{
    "ID123": ["file1", "file2", "file3"],
    "ID999": ["file2", "file3"],
}
```

Then depending on the exact desired output you may eventually have to build a second map with whatever best suits the output format... for example a reverse mapping:

```
revduplicates = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in duplicates.iteritems():
    revduplicates[tuple(v)].append(k)
print(revduplicates)

{
    ('file1', 'file2', 'file3'): ['ID123'],
    ('file2', 'file3'): ['ID999'],
}
```

You will have a couple more steps for the exact output you describe but this should at least get you started.

Comment: so the list in this case is a list of all the filepaths/names.txt?
it then compares every file with each other and puts all the duplicate ID's in a new file?

Comment: Thanks, This was what I was looking for, I will try this out :)

Comment: One more question though. I now have the problem dat it isnt ID123: File1, File2, but the whole file-path, which makes the prints very unreadable. I already tried to name the variables so that it would print the variable name (like file1 = "path/to/file" etc.) and then ( filenames = [file1,file2,file3,file4,file5,file6,file7]), but that doesn't solve the problem. have any tips on that? I think the problem lies with ".append(filename)", but i don't get why it woudn't use the variable name

Comment: It won't use the variable name because a "variable name" is only a reference to the value, and it's the value that get printed. But you can store the file name part of the path (using `os.path.basename(filename)`) instead of the whole path.